# How to cross out term in equation editor in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equation-editor, tex

I would like to cross-out a term in equation inside the equation editor in word 2016.

This the effect I would like to achieve in equation editor in MS Word 2016.
[image]

Can tex commands be made compatible for word?

Comment: I suspect the only way you would be able to do that would be to use an EQ field nested inside the equation. I don't have a specific suggestion as to how to do the cross or (harder) the arrow). Further, it is not entirely straightforward. If you only have a small number of equations with these crossings out I would be inclined to do the entire equation using EQ, or do them in another tool altogether, generate an image, insert that, and if necessary point out in your text why these equations look a little different.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is kind of a disparate one, but it is a solution. The idea is to use latex and MathJax to form a *cancel term*, then copy it to MS Word, and save it as a building block. This is my recipe, and this is how we bake it:

1. Create Html File and paste on it the following code:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
          <script type="text/javascript"
           src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
          </script>
          <title>tex texample</title>
       </head>
       <body>
         $$\require{cancel}$$
         $$x\cancel{+5}+y+\cancel{-5}=0$$
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

   Notice the `\require{cancel}`. It is an important line.
2. Open this file using a browser. You should have an Internet connection, or you have to download MathJax lib, and rewrite the value of src attribute of script tag to reference it (not recommended).
   Now you see the following equation:

   [image]
3. Right click on the equation and select Show Math As > MathML Code, Copy MathML code to MS Word document, and choose *Keep text only*, or simply press: Ctrl+v, Ctrl, T. Or let me just give you a docx file that contains cancel term inside an equation (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1joQgDibWU5HVa-T6NcNzrW2etSfsw8C1).
4. Now you have the equation as a MS Word Equation. Strip the cancel term and save it to the Equation Building Blocks, as shown:
   [image]
5. Now you have it. Whenever you need to insert cancel term, just go to

   > Equation -> Tools design -> Equation

   as illustrated:
   [image]

Sorry for the images. I'm not allowed to post 'em, because it seems that I have a bad reputation.